# Is it possible to use gRPC protobuf along with Spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, grpc-java

I am new to Spring webflux as well as protobuf. I have been reading some stuff and I have found some similarities between them. Like

- Spring webflux could be deployed over netty so does gRPC.
- Both work good for streaming data.
- Both these frameworks are somewhat based on
  Observer design pattern, supporting even based data processing
  approach.

However, still I am not able to find any example out there which combines the power of webflux (reactive programming), gRPC (faster data coding and decoding) and Spring (dependency injection). Are those not compatible?

Answer (score 3):

They are compatible (sort of) and I've been using them together in multiple projects, but recently I switched all machine to machine reactive calls to RSocket (TCP transport) which fits nicely with the Spring Reactor ecosystem.

For reactive gRPC adapter take a look at Salesforce project: [reactive-grpc](https://github.com/salesforce/reactive-grpc/tree/master/reactor)

Also see the comparison between these two techs: [rsocket-vs-grp](https://dzone.com/articles/rsocket-vs-grpc-benchmark)